# MobiLink: Where is Sybase Central storing the actual content of an remote task for mlagent

Tags: sybase, mobilink, sybase-central, mlagent

When creating a remote task inside an MobiLink project with Sybase Central where it is storing the actual content of task (e.g. executing SQL -> Query which shall be executed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's storing them inside project folder of MobiLink project as seperate files with mlt-extension. Format is XML.